# SQL not accepting an INSERT INTO containing a value with colon (":") inside of it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

As my first topic here, I'll try not to write something too bad a post ^^

First, a little context: I'm building a website that intends to use MySQL databases to store various data, as meetings data (date, hour, subject, room, etc.). I want to allow users to add entries to the Meetings table via a form, which I believe works well for now.

My problem is the following: the Hour data I'm storing in my table uses the `hh:mm:ss` format, but it seems that the `:` isn't appreciated.

Each `$meetingStuff` is something I get from the form, `$meetingHour` following the `hh:mm` format, and here follows the codelines defining the query I send to my SQL server.

```
$dateToInsert = str_replace('/', '-', $meetingDate);
$hourToInsert = $meetingHour . ':00');
$sqlStmt = "INSERT INTO Meetings (Date, Hour, Committee, Title, Room, Type, Agenda) VALUES ($dateToInsert, $hourToInsert, $meetingCommittee, $meetingTitle, $meetingRoom, $meetingType, $meetingAgenda);";
```

Here is the error message I get, after having sent the query:

```
/Back-end_Conf_PP_2022/php/meetingFormAction.phpError: INSERT INTO Meetings (Date, Hour, Committee, Title, Room, Type, Agenda) VALUES (03-07-2019, 17:20:00, COM 27, Abracadabra, H, Official, );
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':20:00, COM 27, Abracadabra, H, Official, )' at line 1
```

Which let me think that the problem is the colon operator `:`, but I didn't manage to find how to get past it.

Thank you all for your time and attention :)

PS: Oh, by the way, the agenda value is empty `""` for now but that's "normal".

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and should resolve imminently

Comment: Use PDO and the prepared statements, cause you risk SQL injection

Comment: Make sure that your data type for date, hour is a datetime and time , I guess that your are using `integer` with it , however, you are open to SQL injections

Comment: The problem is you need to quote the value e.g: `...VALUES ('$dateToInsert', '$hourToInsert', '$meetingCommittee',...` but like others suggest, your script is open to SQL injection, use prepare statement for better security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use PDO with prepared statement to solve your problem but, MOST OF ALL, **to avoid SQL Injections**.

`$pdo` has to be a [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) object.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Meetings (Date, Hour, Committee, Title, Room, Type, Agenda) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$dateToInsert, $hourToInsert, $meetingCommittee, $meetingTitle, $meetingRoom, $meetingType, $meetingAgenda]);
```

Comment: Thank you I'm going to try this! By the way, the inputs are being checked in order to prevent SQL injections

Comment: Why do a job when PHP does for you? :)

Comment: Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's